# How to find the closest networkx node to a point with coordinates - python

Tags: python, coordinates, networkx

I created a `Graph` with `Networkx` and its nodes look like the following:

```py
dict(itertools.islice(H.nodes.items(), 3))

> {{'node1': 'lon': coordx_1,
    'lat': coordy_1,
    'name': 'Road1'}, 
    {'node2': 'lon':coordx_2, 
    'lat': coordy_2, 
    'name': 'Road2'}, ...}
```

I also have a serie of individual points with their respective coordinates:

```py
lon1, lat1 = coordx_3, coordy_3 #let's name it 'PointA'
lon2, lat2 = coordx_4, coordy_4 #let's name it 'PointB'
```

Coordinates from the `Graph` and from the individual points are in `EPSG:4326`.

I am trying to identify which node in the `Graph` is the closest to each set of coordinates.
E.g: Which node is the closest to `PointA` and which one is the closest to `PointB`

I found [some codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304137/finding-the-closest-coordinates-to-a-point) online that allow the computation of the shortest distance between two points but I can't seem to manage to apply it to the `Graph` I'm working with as I keep getting :

```py
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is the problem of nearest point detection - you do not need to solve it with networkx.You can use KD trees along with coordinates matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781737/5260876

Comment: Thank you very much @ilia I will check it out.