# Create a matrix with distances between geopoints

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, geolocation

I am struggling with the implementation of my idea to create the matrix of distances in km between EACH pair of stations in NJ Transit Rail. I have data for longitude and latitude of each stop,

[image]

And what I want to do is this table.

[image]
I already looked at some possible ways to achieve this table, but they are more for geometric coordinates rather than geographical. I would use the distance matrix but as I can see it is for another type of coordinates.

Help, please!

Comment: Can you attach actual data that can be copied and not an image?

Comment: Look at this question, it has all the details you need: [distance-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481485/creating-a-distance-matrix/45834105)

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you’re struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for geographical distance, i.e. Haversine distance. From sklearn 0.22.2, you can use [haversine_distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html):

```
x_deg = df[['stop_lat','stop_lon']].values
x_rad = np.deg2rad(x_deg)

# distances in miles
distances = haversine_distances(x_rad,x_rad) * 6371 / 1.6

pd.DataFrame(distances, 
             index=df.stop_name, columns=df.stop_name)
```

and you would get something like this:

```
stop_name         a         b         c
stop_name                              
a          0.000000  1.274556  1.396741
b          1.274556  0.000000  0.871521
c          1.396741  0.871521  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One question. What are the metrics for the answers? km or miles?

Comment: according to the linked doc, you need to multiply that with the Earth's radius to get the actual distance. so you can choose what you pleased.

Comment: Also see updated answer for conversion from degree to radian.

Comment: oh, okay, so if I multiply, which metric will it be?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# You already have the data
data = [[5, 7], [7, 3], [8, 1]]
ctys = ['Boston', 'Phoenix', 'New York']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['xcord', 'ycord'], index=ctys)
df_mat = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
print(df_mat)

            Boston   Phoenix  New York
Boston    0.000000  4.472136  6.708204
Phoenix   4.472136  0.000000  2.236068
New York  6.708204  2.236068  0.000000
```

Comment: *but they are more for geometric coordinates rather than **geographical** *